# Gradient in Spherical coordinate

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Can someone please help me understand the expression inside the red margin?
As far as I know there was suppose to be a minus sign in the right hand side.
It'd be very helpful if someone could write the derivation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lack of a negative sign is because $\vec{\mathfrak{r}}\equiv\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’$ and $\nabla’$ is the gradient with respect to $\mathbf{r}’$, not $\mathbf{r}$:

$$\begin{align}\nabla'\frac{1}{\mathfrak{r}}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}'}[(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')]^{-1/2}\\
&=-\frac12[(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')]^{-3/2}\,2(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}'}(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')\\
&=+\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’|^3}\\
&=\frac{\vec{\mathfrak{r}}}{\mathfrak{r}^3}\\
&=\frac{\hat{\mathfrak{r}}}{\mathfrak{r}^2}
\end{align}$$

If you are not comfortable thinking of a gradient as a derivative with respect to a vector, you can work this out similarly using index notation for the Cartesian components instead.

Comment: Does MathJax have a font with an r that looks like the one in the OP's image?

Comment: Would you also help me understand the integration by parts step done just below the highlighted part. And thanks for the answer. It was really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, that’s too much to explain in comments. Please make it a separate question. But before you do, did you look at product rule 7?

Comment: No, I couldn't find where it's written.

Comment: http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/BridgeBook/book/math/rules